# How do I add info to a list from a class?

Tags: c#

If I have two class like so:

```
public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Job { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
}
```

And then if I do this:

```
var departments = new List<Department>();
Department d = new Department
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "Depart1",
 };

Department d2 = new Department
{
    Id = 2,
    Name = "Depart2",
 };

 departments.Add(d);
departments.Add(d2);
```

How Can I add to the employees List in the Department class with a foreach loop?  When I do this:

```
foreach(Department dmt in departments)
{
    Employee worker = new Employee 
    {
        Name = "Steve",
        Job = "Cleanup",
        Date = "Today",
     };

     dmt.employees.Add(worker );
}
```

I dont get any build errors but nothing is added.  Any suggestions?

Comment: when is the `.employees` list for any department set to a non-null value?

Comment: I'm suprised you're not getting a null reference exception on employees.Add()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't instantiating the `employees` property.  Change your class definition to this:

```
public class Department
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> employees { get; set; }

    public Department()
    {
        employees = new List<Employee> ();
    }
}
```

Or, if you don't want to use a constructor to instantiate the `employees` property, you will just need to ensure that you do this before you attempt to add an `Employee` object to the `List<Employee>`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your public property employees in your Department class
In this scenario, you could do it in the constructor of Department instances.

```
public class Department 
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public List<Employee> employees { get; set; } 
    public Department()
    {
        employees = new List<Employee>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try it like this

```
public class Department 
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public List<Employee> employees { get; set; } 
    public Department()
    {
        employees = new List<Employee>();
    }
} 

foreach(Department dmt in departments)
{
    dmt.employees.Add( new Employee () {

        // InterestedID = ((int)dataReader["JobId"]),
        Name = "Steve",
        Job = "Cleanup",
        Date = "Today",
     });   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would design my class like so, making the Employees List readonly:

```
public class Department 
{
  private readonly List<Employee> _employees = new List<Employee>();

  public int Id { get; set; }     
  public string Name { get; set; }     
  public List<Employee> employees { get { return this._employees; }}       
}
```